# text qualifier of csv missing in excel

Tags: csv

I have created a csv file with semicolon as delimiter and double quote ad text qualifier. But when I open in excel, the first double quote of the rows disappear. When I use text to column wizard selecting semicolon and double quote as   delimiter and text qualifier respectively, the data do not appear properly.

Comment: I'd love to help, but you'll have to elaborate your question. Could you show a few example rows, and elaborate what exactly "the first double quote of the rows disappear" means? And, what "do not appear properly" means. What do you expect? What are you seeing?